# Distance between $W$, a subspace and the vector $v$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have been asked to find an orthonormal basis in the subspace $$W=span\{(1,1,1,1),(-1,4,4,1),(4,-2,2,0)\}.$$

I have used the Gram-Schmidt procedure to find that the basis vectors would be $$(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}),(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{2}{3\sqrt{2}},\frac{2}{3\sqrt{2}},\frac{-1}{3\sqrt{2}}),(\frac{5}{2\sqrt{11}}, \frac{-13}{6\sqrt{11}}, \frac{-1}{6\sqrt{11}}, \frac{-1}{6\sqrt{11}})$$

(I'm not confident that this is correct).

However, the next part of the question asks me to compute the distance between $W$ and the vector $(1,2,3,4)$. How would one do this?

My thinking for the Gram-Schmidt process was as follows:

$$u_1=\frac{v_1}{||v_1||}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$u_2=v_2-(v_2\cdot u_1)u_1=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 4 \\ 4 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}-\Bigg[\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 4 \\ 4 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}\Bigg]
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ -1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Then divide by norm which is $3\sqrt{2}$

So we have that $u_2= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{2}{3\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{2}{3\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{-1}{3\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}$

Then for $u_3$ I did the following

$$u_3=v_3-(v_3 \cdot u_2)u_2-(v_3\cdot u_1)u_1$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ -2 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}-\Bigg[\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ -2 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{2}{3\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{2}{3\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{-1}{3\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}\Bigg] \begin{pmatrix} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{2}{3\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{2}{3\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{-1}{3\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}-\Bigg[\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ -2 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \end{pmatrix}\Bigg] \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ \frac{-13}{3} \\ \frac{-1}{3} \\ \frac{-1}{3} \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Then divide by the norm which is $2\sqrt{11}$

This then gives $$u_3=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{5}{2\sqrt{11}} \\ \frac{-13}{6\sqrt{11}} \\ \frac{-1}{6\sqrt{11}} \\ \frac{-1}{6\sqrt{11}} \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: The "most geometric why" of solving this would be: imagine $W$ as a "plane", and find $W^{\bottom}$ which will be a "line" because $W$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ or dimension $3$.has dimension . Then, find the equation of the line

Comment: Do you remember finding the shortest distance from a point to a line? Or a point to a plane? It's basically the same procedure. A line is a one-dimensional subspace and a plane is two dimensions. Here your space $W$ is 3 dimensional but the shortest distance will still be when the line from your point to the subspace is orthogonal to the space itself. i.e. find the vector from $(1,2,3,4)$ to $W$ such that the vector is orthogonal to $W$ and the distance will be the length of that vector!

Comment: Your basis is not normalized.

Comment: Your solution is to the first question is not correct, it could be easily check that second and third vector are not orthogonal. Additionally their norm is not 1.

Comment: @iiivooo Is that better now?

Comment: @Si.0788 are second and third vector orthogonal? what are the norms of second and third vector?

Comment: @iiivooo I think it's fine now.

Comment: Count the scalar product between second and third. Their scalar product is clearly positive, e.g. their are not orthogonal. There are many videos on youtube how to count Gram-Schmidt algorithm. Please got through them and then add your complete solution, so we can see where is the possible mistake.

Comment: Your calculation of $u_3$ is incorrect. Specifically when evaluating $(v_3 \cdot u_2) u_2$ you forgot the normalization factor for $u_2$.

Comment: @iiivooo I have researched the topic and written up my solution. What do you think now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just put your problem to [WolphramAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Orthogonalize%7B%7B1,1,1,1%7D,%7B%E2%88%921,4,4,1%7D,%7B4,%E2%88%922,2,0%7D%7D) and it shows little different results,
\begin{align}
u_1=&\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)^\top \\
u_2=&\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sqrt 2}{3},\frac{\sqrt 2 }{3},\frac{-1}{3 \sqrt 2}\right)^\top \\
u_3=&\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}},\frac{-5}{6 \sqrt 3},\frac{7}{6 \sqrt 3},\frac{-5}{6 \sqrt 3}\right)^\top
\end{align}
Since you have the same $u_1$ and $u_2$ you have a numerical error somewhere in computing $u_3$.

Now the distance between $x=(1,2,3,4)^\top$ and W is the distance between $x$ and $\hat x$, where $\hat x$ is projection of $x$ into $W$. How do you count $\hat x$? 
That is easy since 
$$\hat x =  [x \cdot u_1] u_1 + [x \cdot u_2] u_2 + [x \cdot u_3] u_3.$$
So the distance between $W$ and $x$ is norm of $x-\hat x$.

Comment: could you help me find the error? I've worked through all of it again and still got the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

The "most geometric approach" for solving this would be: imagine $W$ as a "plane", and:

(1) Find $W^{\bot}$ which will be a "line" because $W$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ or dimension $3$.has dimension.

(2) Find the equation of the line that passes through the point $(1,2,3,4)$ and is parallel to $W^{\bot}$.

(3) Find the intersection point between that line and the plane $W$.

Would you believe me if I tell you that the distance between the point $(1,2,3,4)$ and $W$ is the same distance between the point $(1,2,3,4)$ and the intersection point.

Comment: How would I find the equation of the line that passes through the point $(1,2,3,4)$ and is parallel to $W^\bot$?

Comment: Using the parametric equation $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}=t\cdot \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}$$ where $(a,b,c,d)$ is a vector that generates $W^{\bot}$.